# How do I specify what would normally be in web.config for an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions

I'm creating an Azure Function, and I need to set this parameter what would normally go in the web.config file:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="xxxxxxxx">
```

But Azure Functions doesn't have a web.config. How do I configure stuff that isn't a simple key/value app setting?

The entity framework code is in a class library used by lots of other things, so I can't really use code based config without major hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it in your code. Microsoft documentation with all options is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based#moving-dbconfiguration

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyDbConfiguration))]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext
{
}
```

or

```
[DbConfigurationType("MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssembly")]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext
{
}
```

Comment: Like I said in my question, it's a pain to use code based config without major hassle... Thanks for the answer though